# How to Auto tag Mercurial on Visual Studio Publish?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mercurial, publish, tortoisehg, visualhg

I am using TortoiseHg + VisualHg on Visual Studio 2008. Has anyone found way to automatically create a tag (with the published version number) in Mercurial whenever I do a publish from VS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a custom script to perform the `hg tag` operation as an "AfterPublish" action.  Have a look at the MSBuild documentation:

- [How to: Extend the Visual Studio Build Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx)

You will need to modify your project to add a custom target like this:

```
<Project>
    ...
    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
        <Exec Command="hg tag %(TAGNAME)"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Is there any way to automatically get the current publish version in the target command?

Comment: Yes, see this other SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990216/read-assembly-version-number-in-post-build-event).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [gavinb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544588/how-to-auto-tag-mercurial-on-visual-studio-publish/7240397#7240397) and Sumo's comment. This is the way I did it for my WinForms application:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Target Name="AfterPublish">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).exe">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyIdentities" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <Exec Command="hg tag %(AssemblyIdentities.Version)" />
  </Target>
```