# Read assembly version number in post-build event?

Tags: msbuild

When I change the assembly information to lets say 1.0.0.1 i thought that i could read the version with $(Version) but it seems that it does not change?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `GetAssemblyIdentity` task to retrieve the version :

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).$(OutputType)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyIdentities"/>
  </GetAssemblyIdentity>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <CssOutputFile Condition="'$(CssOutputFile)'==''">
      ..\Styles\master-%(AssemblyIdentities.Version).css
    </CssOutputFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Text="CssOutputFile : $(CssOutputFile)"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: Ok I see, how can I use the value inside a propertygroup?
Like this CssOutputFile Condition=" '$(CssOutputFile)'=='' ">..\Styles\master-VERSION-HERE.css</CssOutputFile>